# Use Field name as a part of another field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hi I'm new to mongo db and i'm facing some issue.

I have a document Like below:

```
CategoryDetails:{
    VariableConfig:{
                    'AB':'B',
                    'CD':'D'
                   }
                }
```

And i'm storing the leaf node value in one field like below:

```
{
 '$project':{
    'LeafNode':{'$literal':'AB'}
 }
}
```

I want to access the value of CategoryDetails.VariableConfig.LeafNode dynamically in query like below:

```
  '$project': {
    'PageNameDetails' : '$CategoryDetails.VariableConfig.LeafNode'
 }
```

Desired Output:
B

But I'ts not giving the output.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You'll probably need to use `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject` to achieve your goal. Can you please post clean samples of your documents and the desired output structure?

Comment: I have document like this CategoryDetails:{
                                                      SubConfig:{
                                                                              'AB':'B',
                                                                               'CD':'D'
                                                                           }
                                                                    }

Comment: I want to access the 'AB''s value in query dynamically where i m storing 'AB' as one field

Comment: I have posted the question properly now please check